# SQlite database not storing double value as string

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am using following code

```
     public boolean addArea(AreaClass area , ArrayList<AreaMarkClass> areaArray)
     {      
         area.id =  getNextAreaId();
        Log.d("longitude", area.longitude);
        Log.d("latitude", area.latitude);

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("_id", area.id);
        initialValues.put("name", area.name);
        initialValues.put("longitude", area.longitude);
        initialValues.put("latitude", area.latitude);
        initialValues.put("zoomLevel", area.zoomLevel);
        initialValues.put("creationDate",area.creationDate);

        try
        {
            mDb.insertOrThrow("TTArea", null, initialValues);
}
```

`area.longitude` is a string whose value is obtained by `String.value` (A Double Value)
Now usually it is something like this `22.323434523464563456`

however when i try to retrieve this value

```
public AreaClass getAreaClassWithAreaId(Integer id)
{
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM TTArea WHERE _id = ?";
    Cursor resultSet =  mDb.rawQuery(queryString, new String[]{id.toString()}); 
    AreaClass area = new AreaClass();
    while(resultSet.moveToNext())
    {
         area = new AreaClass(
                        resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                        resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("name")),
                        resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("longitude")),
                        resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("latitude")),
                        resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("zoomLevel")),
                        resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("creationDate"))
                        );
    }

    resultSet.close();
    return area;
}
```

it somehow rounds it to `22.3234`. In my app i need precise what i am storing. What is this behavior and how can i resolve this?

Comment: What is your table schema? (While SQLite uses "type affinity" in some cases the data type matters.)

Comment: How can i get schema? and how to fix this?

Comment: The "schema" is simply your `CREATE TABLE` statement(s), please post these.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TTArea ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, longitude STRING, latitude STRING  and so on

Comment: To be clear, do the LogCat statements in `addArea()` print the entire number `22.323434523464563456`? Post your `Area` constructor.

Comment: yes it does, i have no idea why it is not showing but i think its resolved when i changed from STRING TO TEXT

Comment: That makes sense, I missed that. I think you should use `REAL` instead of `TEXT`, since you are trying to work with numbers. This way you don't have to convert your Doubles to and from Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these methods when working with SQLite:

```
public static Double stringToDouble (String x)
{
    if (x !=null)
        return Double.parseDouble(x);

    return null;
}

public static String doubleToString (Double y)
{
    if (y != null)
        return String.valueOf(y);

    return null;
}
```

When adding to database transform the double value to string and vice-versa, and please tell me if this solution works

EDIT: The solution is in comments:
"I see you created your table with STRING fields. You can try with TEXT type, works for me."

Comment: I see you created your table with STRING fields. You can try with TEXT type, works for me.