# Why does Double return the wrong data from my DB?

Tags: android, double, decimal

I have a number in my database 2250.67

I fetch it this way

```
Double doubleBalance = (double) getBalance();
```

and this is what it outputs `2250.0`

shouldn't it output `2250.67`

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said

> I have a number in my database 2250.67

I'm assuming datatype for the said dB field is `decimal`

Check if, while fetching the data you have right datatype set in the application code.

Comment: the data type for the db is `DOUBLE`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQLite to store the data, it has to be noted that it supports data types as mentioned [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

If you want to store and use `double` values, you can use the following methods

```
public static Double stringToDouble (String x) {
    if (x !=null)
        return Double.parseDouble(x);
    return null;
}

public static String doubleToString (Double y) {
    if (y != null)
        return String.valueOf(y);
    return null;
}
```

Use `doubleToString()` when you are storing it in the DB and use `stringToDouble()` when you are fetching it from the DB to be used in your application as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295685/10487248).

Comment: I'm using MySQL database, does this still apply?

Comment: @Kennedy It does if you are storing it as string in the database. But, MySQL is already rich when it comes to availability of datatypes. So I wouldn't recommend doing so. Also, I have little knowledge about using MySQL so can't help with your case. Maybe provide some more code like the `getBalance()` method and how you are storing it in the DB. It'll be more easier for everyone to help in that case.

Comment: I'm not storing it in the database, I inputted those figures manually into the DB, and the datatype is `DOUBLE`

Comment: @Kennedy Sorry, but I am not acquainted with using MySQL with JAVA or Android either. Edit your post to add more relevant code. Maybe, I'll be able to help.